# Can´t run Android Emulator with hardware-gles 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, hardware-acceleration

Im trying to run an Android Emulator on Android Studio with Graphics: Hardware-gles 2.0, but when i turn it on, Android Studio shows me the following message:

[image]

But, when i set graphics: Software-gles 2.0 it works fine.

I would like to use hardware acceleration, but I am willing to work with software-GLES 2.0 if necessary.

My computers specs:

- AMD ryzen 7 2700x (Hyper-V ON, SVN ON)
- NVIDA 1660 super Gigabyte OC
- 16 GB RAM DDR4
- Windows 10 21H2 64 bits
- Motherboard is ASUS ROG-STRIX b-450f

Adittional info:

- I have already updated the emulator and every option in the SDK manager
- apparently, it does work correctly with API 28 devices, but not 29 or 30
- I have tried to run the emulator via powershell, and this is the output:

```html
PS C:\Users\andjo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> ./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_29
INFO    | Android emulator version 30.9.5.0 (build_id 7820599) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
```

Thank you for your attention!